# getSupportFragmentManager() undefined in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

i'm getting error on getSupportFragmentManager() that "this method undefine in Fragment", while creating slider menu with sliding tab i prepared code as bellow..

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles1[] = { "Home", "Help", "Contect" };
    // int Titles[] = { R.drawable.ic_content_copy_black_24dp,
    // R.drawable.ic_refresh_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_share_black_24dp };
    int NumOfTabs = 3;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
            false);

        return rootView;

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles1,
            NumOfTabs);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    }
```

and my adapter class for ViewPager is as bellow

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    CharSequence Titles1[];
    int Titles[];
    int NumbOfTabs;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.Titles1 = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        if(arg0 == 0){
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }else if(arg0 == 1){
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }else{
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles1[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

with:

```
getFragmentManager()
```

---

If you are using a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` it will return a `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` (SupportFragmentManager)

If you are using a `android.app.Fragment` it will return a `android.app.FragmentManager`

---

Keep in mind that it handled different that in Activities.Like in the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`. There you have got `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1):

`getSupportFragmentManager()` is used when your `activity` extends `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`. If you are extending `Activity` , you need to use  `getFragmentManager()` instead.

If you are extending `FragmentActivity` , make sure you are importing `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

Also note that `getSupportFragmentManager()` is available for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` not `android.app.Fragment`.

Also you need to return your `rootView` at the end of `onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct import?
This one: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
and not this: import android.app.Fragment;

Edit:
Note that your code after "return rootView" on onCreateView will never be executed because you have a return before.